# Regular expressions in c++11

Tags: c++, regex, linux, c++11

I want to parser cpu info in Linux. I wrote such code:

```
// Returns full data of the file in a string
std::string filedata = readFile("/proc/cpuinfo");

std::cmath results;
// In file that string looks like: 'model name : Intel ...'
std::regex reg("model name: *");
std::regex_search(filedata.c_str(), results, reg);

std::cout << results[0] << " " << results[1] << std::endl;
```

But it returns empty string. What's wrong?

Comment: Don't you mean `cmatch` ? Can you please post the whole code and the contents of `cpuinfo` ?

Comment: See this thread "Difference between regex_match and regex_search?" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628047/difference-between-regex-match-and-regex-search)

Comment: Want to add that it works in VC++2010 with expression corrected by James Kanze in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify any capture in your expression.

Given the structure of `/proc/cpuinfo`, I'd probably prefer a line
oriented input, using `std::getline`, rather than trying to do
everything at once.  So you'ld end up with something like:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( input, line ) ) {
    static std::regex const procInfo( "model name\\s*: (.*)" );
    std::cmatch results;
    if ( std::regex_match( line, results, procInfo ) ) {
        std::cout << "???" << " " << results[1] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It's not clear to me what you wanted as output.  Probably, you also
have to capture the `processor` line as well, and output that at the
start of the processor info line.

The important things to note are:

1. You need to accept varying amounts of white space: use `"\\s*"` for 0 or more, `"\\s+"` for one or more whitespace characters.
2. You need to use parentheses to delimit what you want to capture.

(FWIW: I'm actually basing my statements on `boost::regex`, since I
don't have access to `std::regex`.  I think that they're pretty similar,
however, and that my statements above apply to both.)

Comment: Nice answer, thanks ;). Btw, replace, please `line` with `line.c_str()` in `regex_match`.

Comment: @Ockonal Why the change?  Both are defined in the standard (and both work with `boost::regex`).

Answer (score 5):

Not all compilers support the full C++11 specification yet. Notably, `regex_search` does not work in GCC (as of version 4.7.1), but it does in VC++ 2010.

Comment: see also: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Answer (score 2):

Try `std::regex reg("model_name *: *")`. In my cpuinfo there are spaces before colon.

Comment: Without capture, he's still not going to get the information he needs.