# Using regex_search from the C++ regex library

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

The regex_search function isn't quite behaving as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "Hello world";
    const regex rx("Hello");
    cout << regex_search(str.begin(), str.end(), rx) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0
```

What's going on?

Comment: Remember that C++11 is quite new, and not all compilers support all features yet. Specifically, [GCC do not support `regex_search`yet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11629428/440558).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I guess I'll go look at Boost's regex library now.

Comment: @wenderen : Be sure to look into Boost.Xpressive rather than Boost.Regex if you want to avoid having to build Boost (Xpressive is header-only unlike Regex).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So what is *gcc*'s intention with this oddity? Why then expose the `std::regex_search` function **if it doesn't work** (and his example isn't really an edge case)? I'd rather miss this function than use it while it silently **just doesn't work**.

Comment: @ChristianRau I don't know what the GCC designers think, but I'm guessing it's better to have a complete interface, even if some of the actual functionality behind that interface is missing.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments to the question, older implementations of the C++ standard libraries did not yet support all features in C++11. Of course, [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) being an exception because it was originally built specifically for C++11.

According to [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53631) support for `<regex>` in libstdc++ was only implemented for version 4.9 of GCC. You can check the current status on the [libstdc++ status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011).

One can confirm, that your example works with GCC 4.9 while still failing with GCC 4.8.