# why boost::regex_match returns me always false?

Tags: regex, boost

It is obvious that here must me match, but this code stills returns false.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main() {
  cout << regex_match("some text", regex("text")) << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't know this `regex_match` function, but it possibly *auto-anchors* the pattern with `^` and `$`. Try with `.*text`.

Comment: @sp00m Yes, replacing `regex("text")` by `regex(".*text")` would match as well, as it covers the complete input `"some text"`. (`regex_search` is the simple way, however.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`regex_match` must match all of the given character sequence. Try `regex_search` instead.

Comment: thanks, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628047/difference-between-regex-match-and-regex-search