# Difference between std::regex_match & std::regex_search?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, visual-studio-2013, gcc4.9

Below program has been written to fetch the "Day" information using the C++11 [std::regex_match](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) & [std::regex_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search). However, using the first method returns `false` and second method returns `true`(expected). I read the documentation and already existing SO question related to this, but I do not understand the difference between these two methods and when we should use either of them?  Can they both be used interchangeably for any common problem?

[Difference between regex_match and regex_search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628047/difference-between-regex-match-and-regex-search)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<regex>

int main()
{
    std::string input{ "Mon Nov 25 20:54:36 2013" };
    //Day:: Exactly Two Number surrounded by spaces in both side
    std::regex  r{R"(\s\d{2}\s)"};
    //std::regex  r{"\\s\\d{2}\\s"};
    std::smatch match;

if (std::regex_match(input,match,r)) {
        std::cout << "Found" << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Did Not Found" << "\n";
    }

    if (std::regex_search(input, match,r)) {
        std::cout << "Found" << "\n";
        if (match.ready()){
            std::string out = match[0];
            std::cout << out << "\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Did Not Found" << "\n";
    }
}
```

## Output

```
Did Not Found

Found

 25
```

Why first regex method returns `false` in this case?. The `regex` seems to be correct so ideally both should have been returned `true`. I ran the above program by changing the `std::regex_match(input,match,r)` to `std::regex_match(input,r)` and found that it still returns `false.`

Could somebody explain the above example and, in general, use cases of these methods?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`regex_match` only returns `true` when the entire input sequence has been matched, while `regex_search` will succeed even if only a sub-sequence matches the `regex`.

Quoting from N3337,

> *§28.11.2/2* `regex_match` *[re.alg.match]*
>   *Effects:* Determines whether there is a match between the regular expression `e`, and **all of the character sequence `[first,last)`**. `...` Returns `true` if such a match exists, `false` otherwise.

The above description is for the `regex_match` overload that takes a pair of iterators to the sequence to be matched. The remaining overloads are defined in terms of this overload.

The corresponding `regex_search` overload is described as

> *§28.11.3/2* `regex_search` *[re.alg.search]*
>   *Effects:* Determines whether there is **some sub-sequence within `[first,last)`** that matches the regular expression `e`. `...` Returns `true` if such a sequence exists, `false` otherwise.

---

In your example, if you modify the `regex` to `r{R"(.*?\s\d{2}\s.*)"};` both `regex_match` and `regex_search` will succeed (but the match result is not just the day, but the entire date string).

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cecafd11147af0a) of a modified version of your example where the day is being captured and displayed by both `regex_match` and `regex_search`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could you please explain about the why we needed to changed from match[0] to match[1] to get the exact result in both the cases?. I mean it is about std::smatch uses understanding.

Comment: @MantoshKumar I added parentheses around the date field `(\d{2})` to create a capture group. From the `match_results` [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/operator_at), `match[0]` always returns the entire matched expression, while `match[1]` returns the first sub-match and so on. In this case, we only had one capture group, for the day, and so that is stored in the first sub-match.

Comment: From a performance standpoint, I bet regex_match is computationally much faster than regex_search, on average, due to the ability to return false immediately when a match fails.  In contrast, regex_search is going to check if substrings match the pattern, so in most cases, if not all cases, regex_search will be slower.  So take that into consideration when choosing between these functions.

Answer (score 21):

It's very simple. `regex_search` looks through the string to find if any portion of the string matches the regex. `regex_match` checks if the whole string is a match for the regex.  As a simple example, given the following string:

```
"one two three four"
```

If I use `regex_search` on that string with the expression `"three"`, it will succeed, because `"three"` can be found in `"one two three four"`

However, if I use `regex_match` instead, it will fail, because `"three"` is not the whole string, but only a part of it.