# Regexp matching fails with invalid special open parenthesis

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11, match

I am trying to use regexps in c++11, but my code always throws an `std::regex_error` of `Invalid special open parenthesis.`. A minimal example code which tries to find the first duplicate character in a string:

```
std::string regexp_string("(?P<a>[a-z])(?P=a)"); // Nothing to be escaped here, right?
std::regex  regexp_to_match(regexp_string);
std::string target("abbab");
std::smatch matched_regexp;
std::regex_match(target, matched_regexp, regexp_to_match);
for(const auto& m: matched_regexp)
{
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

Why do I get an error and how do I fix this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues here:

- `std::regex` flavors do not support named capturing groups / backreferences, you need to use *numbered* capturing groups / backreferences
- You should use [`regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) rather than [`regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) that [requires a full string match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696250/difference-between-stdregex-match-stdregex-search).

Use

```
std::string regexp_string(R"(([a-z])\1)");
std::regex regexp_to_match(regexp_string);
std::string target("abbab");
std::smatch matched_regexp;
if (std::regex_search(target, matched_regexp, regexp_to_match)) {
    std::cout << matched_regexp.str() << std::endl;
}
// => bb
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/EXwO6T)

The `R"(([a-z])\1)"` raw string literal defines the `([a-z])\1` regex that matches any lowercase ASCII letter and then matches the same letter again.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript says that ECMAScript (the default type for `std::regex`) requires `(?=` for positive lookahead.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can correct the example then? My goal is to have labeled capture groups

Comment: Groups that capture what? Do you need `"(a[a-z])(a)"` or something?

Comment: I need to find reoccuring patterns, so I want to have groups that capture only the same characters for a given capture group label.

Comment: Do you mean `"(a[a-z])\1"` to capture "ab" in "abab"? You can look for identical matches by using back references: "\<digit>".

Comment: In this example, I wanted to capture "bb": https://regex101.com/r/DqgnAs/1 Can I do it with proper labels?

Comment: So probably simply `([a-z])\1`: a group that captures a single lowercase character and immediately a backreference to it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your regex crashes for you is because named groups not supported by std::regex. However you can still use what is available to find the first duplicate char in string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "abc def cde";
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex r("(\\w).*?(?=\\1)");

    if (std::regex_search(s, m, r))
        std::cout << m[1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
c
```