# Split a mathematical expression using regex

Tags: c++, regex, expression

I want to split the following mathematical expression `-1+33+4.4+sin(3)-2-x^2` into tokens using regex. I use the following site to test my regex expression [link](https://regex101.com/r/RC3isu/1), this says that nothing wrong. When I implement the regex into my C++, throwing the following error `Invalid special open parenthesis` I looked for the solution and I find the following stackoverflow site [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316942/regexp-matching-fails-with-invalid-special-open-parenthesis) but it do not helped me solve my problem.
My regex code is `(?<=[-+*\/^()])|(?=[-+*\/^()])`. In the C++ code I do not use `\`.

The other problem is that I do not know how to determine the minus sign is an unary operator or a binary operator, if the minus is an unary operator I want to look like this `{-1}`

I want the tokens looks like this : `{-1,+,33,+4.4,+,sin,(,3,),-,2,-,x,^,2}`

The unary minus can be anywhere in the string.

If I do not use `^` it still wrong.

code:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& s, std::string rgx_str) {
      std::vector<std::string> elems;
      std::regex rgx (rgx_str);
      std::sregex_token_iterator iter(s.begin(), s.end(), rgx);
      std::sregex_token_iterator end;
      while (iter != end)  {
          elems.push_back(*iter);
          ++iter;
      }
      return elems;
}
int main() {
    std::string str = "-1+33+4.4+sin(3)-2-x^2";
    std::string reg = "(?<=[-+*/()^])|(?=[-+*/()^])";
    std::vector<std::string> s = split(str,reg);
    for(auto& a : s)
        cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can we assume that the unary minus can only occur at the string start?

Comment: There are several flavors of regular expressions in use. Without looking up C++'s `std::regex` implementation, it's likely that this syntax  doesn't match what `std::regex` expects. Finally, on the topic of the minus sign, for this and other reasons its simply not feasible to expect to parse arbitrarily complex mathematical expressions using regular expressions alone. Real parsers employ a regex-based lexer with a separate grammar parsing phase that uses an LALR(1) parser, typically, and treats `-` as an unary operator, and implements it directly on numeric constant operands.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no the unary minus can be anywhere

Comment: Could the ^ sign be the issue? Isn't that a reserved character representing the end of a string?

Comment: @J.Lengel if I do not use ^ it still wrong

Comment: Then you need to define the contexts where the `-` should be kept with a digit.

Comment: What happens if you prepend all reserved characters (?, +, *, (, ), ^, etc.) with a backslash?

Comment: Given you are trying to match them and they are not part of the syntax

Comment: If I just use (?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/]) it still wrong, and still the same error

Comment: Now I solved the unary minus problem, so that is not the problem. I do not have to use - sign at the positive lookbehind part

Comment: You can't do this with regular expressions. You need to write a proper scanner and expression parser.

Comment: @user207421 I do not think that, now I know how to split the string, Currently the only problem is the error.

Comment: Currently the problem is that you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I agree. While this does not answer your question, I would suggest using some recursive parser (That way you can read and parse the string at the same time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ uses a [modified ECMAScript regular expression grammar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript) for its `std::regex` by default. It does support lookaheads `(?=)` and `(?!)`, but not lookbehinds. So, the `(?<=)` is not a valid `std::regex` syntax.

There is [a proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1844r1.html) to add this in C++23, but it is not currently implemented.