# How to test a string that contains a random value?

Tags: c++, googlemock

My mock class looks like this:

```
struct StringEater {
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD1( ExecuteCommand, void( const char* ) ); 
};
```

and the string consist of part that doesn't change, and small part that I can not set in test. Something like this :

> Command 825 finished

but it can be

> Command 123 finished

or  `"Command " + any number + " finished"`.

The method from the mock class is always called.

So, how do I set the test? This obviously can not be used:

```
StringEater mock;
EXPECT_CALL( mock, ExecuteCommand( StrEq( expectedJsonCmd ) ) ).Times( 1 );
```

What do I need to put for the matcher?

---

This works (thanks to J):

```
TEST( abc, some )
{
    struct StringEater {
        MOCK_CONST_METHOD1( ExecuteCommand, void( const char* ) );
    };

    StringEater eater;
    EXPECT_CALL( eater, ExecuteCommand( MatchesRegex( "Command\\s([0-9]*)\\sfinished" ) ) ).Times( 1 );
    eater.ExecuteCommand( "Command 643 finished" );
}
```

Comment: This is so trivially easy that there has to be a catch... what are the exact requirements here?  I can't believe a senior software engineer and 6-year SO vet with 36k doesn't know how to parse a shockingly regular string.

Comment: @J... Literally never did regex. Tried using `MatchesRegex` but failed :(

Comment: @J... Ok, with some fixes, I made it work. Thanks, but why not answer?

Comment: Because, this is basically : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285739/327083  Also, you hadn't included what you had tried and why it didn't work, it wasn't clear what the exact requirements are (did "number" mean "integer"?, case sensitivity? variable whitespace?  etc?).  It's a weak question...

Comment: Also worth knowing what platform(s) you're targeting.  Regex in gmock sorely lacks consistency between platforms.

Answer (score 0):

So it will always be the string `"Command"` followed by an integral number followed by the string `"finished"`?

Then it could be tested by attempting to extract these three parts from the string, comparing the first and third parts to the expected strings.

Something like

```
std::istringstream iss(the_input_string);
std::string s1, s3;
int i2;

if (iss >> s1 >> i2 >> s3)
{
    if (s1 == "Command" && s3 == "finished")
    {
        // Test succeeded
    }
    else
    {
        // Test failed
    }
}
else
{
    // Failed, not correct format
}
```

Comment: Actually the string is more complex, and not that simple. I am looking for a gmock matcher to test that string. Now I am thinking to use `StartsWith` and `EndsWith`, but I am hoping someone can suggest something better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using regexp where you check whether the string begins with "Command" and ends with "finished" and extract the number as a group.

Similar problem was described in another post:
[Regex C++: extract substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627440/regex-c-extract-substring)