# Regex to find a substring with ignoring few characters

Tags: c++

I could have few valid strings in my application. Such valid strings may include:

```
 "attached:yes blocked:yes"        #No ()
 "attached:yes blocked:(yes)"      #Blocked has ()
 "attached:(yes) blocked:yes"      #Attached has ()
 "attached:(yes) blocked:(yes)"    #Both have ()
```

If I find `blocked:(yes)` or `blocked:yes` in any of the above strings, I would like to have the indices of the start and end of the matched part. So basically ignore `(` or `)`

**EXAMPLES**

`attached:yes blocked:yes` should give two indices start and end of substring of `blocked:yes`, which is `(13, 24)`

`attached:yes blocked:(yes)` should give two indices start and end of substring of `blocked:(yes)`, which is `(13, 26)`

Comment: Looking at your tags: How is this C++ related?

Comment: @IgorS.K.I want a solution in c++ if it is specific to c++

Comment: Have you look into using regular expressions to solve your problem?

Comment: @acarlstein I did but was not able to come up with one.

Answer (score 0):

1st. Find out what library can you use to utilize regular expressions.

2nd. Below is an example of the regular expression.|

What I am saying in the regular expression is to obtain group 1 and group 2 where the values can be 'yes' or '(yes)'

> attached:([(]?yes[)]?) blocked:([(]?yes[)]?)

[image]
The more sure you will be using the regex library:

```
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
```

Here are some links that talk about regular expressions in C++:

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/stdregex.html
- [Regex C++: extract substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627440/regex-c-extract-substring)
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regex-regular-expression-in-c/

Let me know if this is pointing you to the right direction, else I can remove this answer.